# Fastest way to insert elements from Ruby hash to SQLite 3

Tags: ruby, hash, sqlite, insert

I have a Ruby hash with variables:

- a two-element array of strings
- an integer

I have tried the two following ways to insert the elements from the hash to a SQLite 3 DB:

```
myRubyHash.each do |k, v|
   x=[k[0],k[1],v] 
   db.execute "INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES ( ?, ?, ? )", x
end
```

And,

```
myRubyHash.each do |x|
   db.execute "INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES ( ?, ?, ? )", x
end
```

The first being considerably faster (but still quite slow). Is there a faster way to go about this?

If it helps, my SQLite 3 table was created by:

```
rows = db.execute <<-SQL
  CREATE TABLE Assoc_words_p (
    name1 varchar(30),
    name2 varchar(30),
    val int,
    PRIMARY KEY (name1,name2)
  );
SQL
```

Thanks

Comment: Rather than ask us which is the fastest, take the time to learn to use `Benchmark`. It comes with Ruby and is designed to help you quickly figure out the fastest ways to do something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the prepare statement can be used as follows:

```
stmnt1 = db.prepare( "INSERT INTO Table(name1,name2,val) VALUES (?, ?, ?)" )
myRubyHash.each do |k, v|
    stmnt1.execute(k[0],k[1],v/2)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, `Hash#each` is just not a fast method, and I expect that's what's causing the performance concerns. The first thing that comes to mind in terms of performance is wondering why there's a hash there at all - it seems like the faster way to go would be to put your data into the database directly and skip the hash altogether.